# What is torch.randn((1, 5))?

Tags: pytorch

I'm confused as to why there are double parantheses instead of just `torch.randn(1,5)`.

Is `torch.randn(1,5)` the same thing as `torch.randn((1,5))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the definition of this function [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.randn.html#torch.randn).

> size (int...) – a sequence of integers defining the shape of the output tensor. Can be a variable number of arguments or a collection like a list or tuple.

```
>>> import torch
>>> a = torch.randn(1,5)
>>> b = torch.randn((1,5))
>>> a.shape == b.shape
True
```

Therefore, you can use either `a` or `b` since they have the same shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both variants: `(1, 2)` and `1, 2`. Because of python asterisk magics:

```py
torch.randn(*size, *, out=None, dtype=None, layout=torch.strided, device=None, requires_grad=False) → Tensor
```

the first `*size` captures all positional arguments passed to the function, when passing `1, 2` function will pack it to `(1, 2)`.

the second `*` turns any parameters that follow it to be keyword-only parameters, to avoid situations like this: `randn(1, 2 None, torch.strided, "cuda", True)`, forcing you to `randn(1, 2, out=None, dtype=None, layout=torch.strided, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)`